# What is the metric used here?

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose we consider a set of all $n\times n$ matrices and if we consider them as metric space what is the metric we are using?

Is that determinant the metric we are following or is there any metric 
(other than discrete metric)

( I'm working on the problem : is $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ dense in $M(n,\mathbb R)$

Answer (score 2):

Since the set of square matrices of size $n$ is finite-dimensional, it does not matter: all norms are equivalent, they induce the same topology.

By the way, there is a ambiguity in your question, the title says *norm* and the core of the question *metric*, the claim above is false for metrics.

Comment: I'm sorry ! i'm interested in metrics ,I think norm also a metric .its my fault ,I will correct it, thanks!

Comment: You should tell us more about the context of the problem you are working on, it will help us guessing what is the metric used.

Comment: I added it !...